# HttpURLConnection not working for multilingual site

Tags: java, selenium, http, httpresponse

In my project i am verifying the links for few landing pages from an excel sheet using Selenium and Java. Below is the code i am using:

```
public static void verifyConnection(String linkUrl) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(linkUrl);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    try {
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("resp 200"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("resp error");   
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The problem here is, when the linkUrl is something like https://www.google.com/ the response works fine, but when i do the same for Spanish version of our site with links like https://es.google.com/ or https://espanol.google.com/ i get Connection timed out exception.

Could someone advise, what i am missing?

Note: The above google links may not be valid, it is just to explain my scenario.

Comment: you are getting this exception because domain does not exist: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: es.google.com
Try with an existent domain

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have mentioned in my question that the google links are just for explaining my scenario. I cannot share the original links due to security concerns.

Comment: Imposible to help you. Find in google some similar link, replicate your issue and share us the links. Also **Connection timed out exception.** means page does not exist!! and this error is not related to languages or any internalization feature in web pages!

Comment: Probably the issue is that your web browser using one proxy and URLConnection is using some other one.